# What impacts on a computers ability to record footage from a camera?

Tags: memory, video, cpu, streaming

I was wondering if any could give me a brief overview of what affects a computers ability to record footage from a camera. I'm confused as to what makes one computer/setup good for recording when another seemingly higher spec machine isn't able to cope with recording. I'm currently working on a project where I'm using a RPi 0 to record/stream footage.

For example a GoPro camera can record in at 4k 60fps but a Raspberry Pi 0 can struggle to record at 640x480 at 5fps (I'm using motioneye to record/stream which is quite intensive so I'm sure this could be improved upon a bit but I haven't really managed to get significantly better results from the Pi without cutting out the streaming aspect of my project). I'm not sure which is technically the higher spec machine here as the details on the GoPro's CPU are hard to find, although I believe it has a significantly higher amount of ram than a Pi0?

What adds to my confusion is that the company I work for uses a tablet + camera system as part of an in-car DVR setup. We use Panasonic tablets with i5 processors. On the face of it I'd expect to be able to record at full HD 30 fps at least because they're quite powerful tablets, but we can't push the recording past 756x536 resolution at 12fps and even then we seem to skip frames a fair bit in the recordings. Just changing the resolution in the DVR software to full HD will then cause the DVR software to crash and I have to change the resolution using the config files to get it to open again.

When I first started working there and learnt about the system I just put it down to poor software (its 6/7 years old now and never been changed) but I was recently told by my boss that another company using the same software but another type of tablet (Getac) are apparently recording at 4k despite their tablets using intel atom processors (both panasonic/getac tablets have 4gb ram so there's no ram difference to account for).

From learning about that and my own experience with a raspberry pi vs gopro I'm completely confused as to what it is that makes a device capable of recording at high resolutions/fps. I know that multiple things will affect the quality of the recording CPU/RAM/Cooling/streaming vs not streaming for a few and I think I understand why the pi's performance is so low compared to a gopro/actual cameras (its running a much more complex OS than a camera and is much more limited by the ram and the bandwidth of the CSI bus), but I just can't get my head round the work example. Any searches I've done just bring back pages of results about possible fixes for choppy footage so I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: You're meeting the 'one-trick pony vs jack of all trades' trade-off. Do one job & do it well, vs try to be capable of doing them all but optimised for none.

Comment: Real-world example. I have an old but still highly capable Mac, 12 (real) cores of 3.46Ghz Xeon. Struggles to reach 15fps recording 720p from a webcam, sings like a bird recording from my Nikon DSLR. All it needs is for the Nikon to handle all the front-end processing & hand it a fait accompli as a data stream. If it tries to do it all itself it can't keep up.